# map emmeans from a list of linear models in R

Tags: r, dictionary, linear-regression, tidyverse, emmeans

I have a list of over ~100 linear models and I want to take the estimated means and standard errors for each model.

Let's use `mtcars` as an example.

`library(tidyverse); library(magrittr); library(emmeans)`

```
mtcars %<>% 
  mutate(
    cyl = as.factor(cyl)
  )

df <- mtcars %>% select(cyl, hp, mpg)
```

I can easily get the estimated means and standard errors for each model with `emmeans`:

```
mod <- lm(hp ~ cyl, data = df)
emmeans(mod, "cyl")
```

But what if I have a list of models?

```
list_lm <- df %>% 
   select(-c(cyl)) %>%
   map(function(dv) lm(dv ~ df$cyl, data = .))
```

I cannot use:

```
emmeans(list_lm$hp, "cyl")
Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed
```

And ideally, I want something that would give me these statistics for all the models. Something like `broom::tidy` for the coefficients of the model, but for `emmeans`:

```
list_lm %>% 
   map(broom::tidy)
```

Comment: Somebody asked me once before. I think you need a more general `map` function that handles two arguments (`map2`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuitions were right. The solution requires saving intermediate results in list columns and then unpacking them, but given the structure of emmeans output, `broom::tidy()` is not necessary. Just convert emmeans output to a list column of data.frames and `unnest()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(emmeans)

ds_mtcars <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) 

ds_nest <- 
  ds_mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  nest() 

foo_model <- function(data){
  lm(hp ~ cyl, data = data)
}

ds_nest <- ds_nest %>% mutate(model = map(.x = data, .f = foo_model))

ds_temp <- 
  ds_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    emmeans = pmap(
      .l = list(
        object = model, 
        specs = "cyl"
      ),
      .f = emmeans
    )
  ) 

ds_temp %>% 
  mutate(emm2 = map(emmeans, data.frame)) %>% 
  unnest(emm2)
```

Also the `purrr` functions `map()` and `pmap()` can be a mind bender, but I did my best to walk myself and new users through these functions on my [blog](http://www.josephtpowers.com/post/herding-cats-with-list-columns-and-purrr/).

Comment: Almost there! The problem is that I don't want to run the same model for different groups in a factor. I want to run a model with the same predictors while changing the outcome. I thought about creating a list of my outcomes: `dv <- quos(hp, mpg)`. Creating a function that could use two arguments: `foo_model <- function(data, dv){
  lm(dv ~ cyl, data = data)
}` And then applying the mapping: `ds_nest <- ds_nest %>% mutate(model = map2(.x = data, .y = dv, .f = foo_model))`. The problem is that this creates a column larger than the nested dataframe...

Comment: @juanpabloospina, try using gather() to gather all DVs into one column. Then group_by dv and use the above code.

Comment: Instead of `pmap`, I would do `mutate(emmeans = map2(model, data, ~as.data.frame(emmeans(.x, "cyl", data = .y))) %>% unnest(emmeans)`.